# How to add quantity in existing item in DataGridView - vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

The problem exists when an item is already in the `DataGridView`, then when I input again the same item, the quantity and total does not increment or add. It will just list the same item.

e.g.

```
Item Code  ProductName  Unit   Item        Description Price  Quantity Total  Discount
06-098     Biogesic     500mg  Paracetamol             5.50   1        5.50   0.00
```

It has `TextBox` to input the barcode and it will list the item in the `DataGridView`.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub txtbxBarcode_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtbxBarcode.TextChanged
    GetProductInfo()
End Sub

Private Sub GetProductInfo()
    Dim discountAmount As Double
    Dim medicineName, unit As String
    Try
        SQL = "SELECT product_code, Medicine_name, Unit, Description, Price, medicineID FROM medicine_info WHERE barcode = '" & txtbxBarcode.Text & "'"
        ConnDB()
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(SQL, conn)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

        If dr.Read = True Then
            txtbxItemCode.Text = dr("product_code")
            unit = dr("Unit")
            medicineName = dr("Medicine_name")
            txtbxItemDesc.Text = dr("Description")

            'Validate Discount
            If isDiscount = True Then
                discountAmount = Val(dr("Price")) * (Val(discountPercent) / 100)
                txtbxPrice.Text = Format(Val(dr("Price")) - discountAmount, "#,##0.00")
            Else
                txtbxPrice.Text = Format(dr("Price"), "#,##0.00")
                discountAmount = 0
            End If
            'Validate Quantity
            If isQuantity = True Then
                txtbxQuantity.Text = noOfItems
            Else
                txtbxQuantity.Text = 1
            End If
            txtbxTotal.Text = Format(Val(txtbxPrice.Text.Replace(",", "")) * Val(txtbxQuantity.Text), "#,##0.00")
            'Adding Item to Gridview to Display
            dgv.Rows.Add(dr("medicineID"), dr("product_code"), dr("Medicine_name"), dr("Unit"), dr("Description"), txtbxPrice.Text, txtbxQuantity.Text, txtbxTotal.Text, Format(discountAmount * Val(txtbxQuantity.Text), "#,##0.00"))
            'Get Basket Info
            BasketInformation()
            'Clear Barcode text field
            txtbxBarcode.Clear()
            'Set Discount to Zero
            discountPercent = 0
            isDiscount = False
            'Set Quantity to False
            isQuantity = False
            noOfItems = 1
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    Finally
        cmd.Dispose()
        conn.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can improve your question. Please read [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). When your code shows your precise problem with nothing extra, you are showing respect to those who volunteer to help you.

Comment: You can help us help you by formatting your so we don't have scroll it.

Comment: You should add/update the underlying datasource of the datagridview, not the datagridview values themselves

Answer (score 0):

What I do is loop through the datagridview and look for the matching record i'm going to insert, if there is add +1 to a column, if there isn't insert the row.

Example:

```
For each row as DataGridViewRow in datagridview1.Rows
    If row.Cells(0).Value = dr("ID") Then
         row.Cells(6).Value = Integer.Parse(row.Cells(6).Value) + 1
         Exit Sub 'Exit Sub for the purpose of not triggering the row add code since there is an existing record already.
    End IF
Next

datagridview1.rows.add(....)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should handle this with the data before placing it into a datagridview.  Then when you have the correct data you can just set it as the datasource.

Also for this to work you need to use a datatable instead of reading records row by row.  Filling the datatable looks like this..

```
Dim myTable = new DataTable
Using adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    adapter.Fill(myTable)
End Using
```

And editing the data table looks like this..

```
For x as Integer = myTable.rows.Count - 1 to 1
    For y as Integer = x - 1 to 0
        If myTable.rows(x).Item("Item Code") = myTable.rows(y).Item("Item Code") Then
            myTable.rows(x).Item("Quantity") = myTable.rows(x).Item("Quantity") + 1
            myTable.rows(x).Item("Total") = myTable.rows(x).Item("Total") + myTable.rows(y).item("Total")
            myTable.rows(y).Delete()
        End If
    Next
Next

myTable.acceptChanges()
dgv.dataSource = myTable 'this will put all rows from myTable into the dgv
```

Hope this helps!